# doc.data() return empty object attribute, but it is here on console.log

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, vuejs2, google-cloud-firestore

I'm getting a document `doc` from Firestore, and put it in `this.post`. This document has an Object "thumbnail" as an attribute. `doc.data()` does log the thumbnail properly, but not `this.post`, the thumbail object seems to be empty in `this.post`. Any ideas why ?

Here's the code:

```
db.collection('websites').doc('xxx').collection('xxx').doc('xxx').get().then(doc => {
  if (doc.exists) {
    this.post = doc.data()
    console.log(doc.data())
    console.log(this.post)
  } else { console.log('No such data') }
}).catch(function(error) { console.log('Error getting document:', error) })
```

Here the logs:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried accessing any of the properties, eg `this.post.thumbnail.name`? Vue's _observable_ objects don't render very nicely in the standard console. You get better inspections from the Vue Devtools browser extension

Comment: You're right, `this.post.thumbnail.name` is working. I'll try with Vue Devtools as well. Thank you.